# Need to append data in a database column

Tags: php, sql, legacy

I'm working on an old legacy system.  It breaks all kinds of rules from normalization to common sense, but alas I'm stuck with it.  That being said here it goes.

**Question:**

How would I append a name to a field without getting rid of the existing names in that field?  Also, how do I do this over and over again? Same name for the appending, but different names that I need to keep intact that are unique to each row in the database.

**Example: Rows as they are in the name column:**

"Donnie/Mike/Daniel"

"Donnie/James"

"Steve"

**Example: Rows after the script in the name colum:**

"Donnie/Mike/Daniel/Dee"

"Donnie/James/Dee"

"Steve/Dee"

I'm thinking SQL will not be enough here and I'll have to write a script.  What does SO think? Besides the usual sickening feeling you naturally get from legacy apps.

Comment: Why wouldn't be enough a concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax in SQL Server:

```
update table
    set field = field+'/'+<newval>
where <i want the new val>
```

In other databases, the concatenation operation might be:
         set field = field || '/' || 
         set field = concat(field, '/', )